# How to do i write mysql distinct query to Elasticesearch

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I'm converting my PHP MySQL application to Elasticsearch, 
Here is my PHP MySQL query and how to write this query into Elasticseach(Version 5.5)

I tried to write aggregation but the result counts mismatch from the old MySQL result counts.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT offerName, `OfferID`, `duration`, `price`, `numChannels`, providerName) AS "totalRecords" FROM `video` WHERE `active` = 'Y'
```

Here is my Elasticsearch query:

```
{
 "size": 0,
"query":

        { "bool": {
            "should": [ 
                    { "match": { "active": "Y" }}
                ]
            }
        }, 
"aggs": {
    "count_by_OfferID": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "offerID"
        }
    },
    "count_by_offerName":{
          "terms": {
            "field": "offerName"
        }
    },
    "count_by_duration":{
         "terms": {
            "field": "duration"
        }
    },
     "count_by_price":{
         "terms": {
            "field": "price"
        }
     },
       "count_by_downloadSpeed":{
         "terms": {
            "field": "downloadSpeed"
        }
     },
     "count_by_numChannels":{
         "terms": {
            "field": "numChannels"
        }
     },
       "count_by_providerName":{
         "terms": {
            "field": "providerName"
        }
     }
        }

}
```

Comment: Post your aggregation please

Comment: can you post your elasticQuery here ?

Comment: I have update my elasticsearch query, please check it, this the way to write query to get distinct values in ES or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should revise your mapping so that you can get the answer more efficiently, but Elasticsearch's `DISTINCT COUNT` is called `cardinality` aggregation, and it supports ad-hoc [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_script_2). I hope I understood your question correctly.

> The cardinality metric supports scripting, with a noticeable performance hit however since hashes need to be computed on the fly.